# Injectivity and Surjectivity of set of all functions.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B$ be non-empty sets and $f\colon A\to B$ be a function.
Let $C$ be a set with at least two elements. Denote by $\text{Map}(A,C)$ the set of all functions from A to C. Denote by $\text{Map}(B,C)$ the set of all functions from $B$ to $C$.

Define $f^{*}\colon \text{Map}(B,C)\to \text{Map}(A,C)$ by $f^{*}(g)= g \circ f$ for any $g\in\text{Map}(B,C)$

Consider the statements below:

(A) The function $f$ is surjective.

(B) The function $f^{*}$ is injective.

a) Suppose A holds. Does B hold then?

b) Suppose B holds. Does A hold then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties (A) and (B) are equivalent.

Suppose (A) holds true and let $f^*(g)=f^*(h)$. Then $g\circ f=h\circ f$. Let $y\in B$ arbitrary. By the surjectivity of $f$ there is some $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$.
So $g(y)=g(f(x))=h(f(x)=h(y)$, i.e. $g=h$.

Now assume (B) and that $f$ is *not* surjective. Define $g(x)=c$ for all $x\in B$ with $c\in  C$. By assumption there is some $d\in C$ different from $c$. Define $h$ by $h(x)=c$ for $x\in f(A)$ and by $h(x)=d$ If $x\in B\setminus f(A)$. Then $g\not=h$ but  $f^*(g)=f^*(h)$, a contradiction.